# Oracle, Hibernate, Group By, LISTAGG

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have table "Values":

```
int id;
double amount;
Date date;
String cryptoName;
```

I need receive result with "date" and list of "cryptoName" and receive something like:

```
             btc       ltc       drk      42coin
27-DEC-14    0.2       5.0       100.0    0.01
28-DEC-14    0.22      5.5       99.5     0.02
29-DEC-14    0.23      6.1       100.6    0.03
30-DEC-14    0.25      6.0       101.2    0.03
```

I can do this:

```
select "Values"."date", LISTAGG("amount", ', ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "cryptoName") as "result" from "Values" GROUP BY "Values"."date"
```

But in this case I receive two columns: "date" and "result" with my list, but I need to receive "date" column, and several columns, depend on how much unique "cryptoName" in table
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As of 11g R1 onward you can use PIVOT operator. see for example:
http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php

Or you can use DECODE function along with SUM, if you know all unique values of column ctyptoName like this:

```
select date,
sum(decode(cryptoName,'value1',amount,0)) as Value1
,sum(decode(cryptoName,'value2',amount,0)) as Value2
,...
from Values
group by date
```

Comment: but I don't know how unique values will be, it's depends on count of unique "cryptoName"